# Why do I get NULL values in this array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have select lists on a page and I am iterating through all select lists. The values are "default", "Excused Absent", and "Excused Late". Default is basically "Select...". I don't want to pass this to the server or do any processing with it since it's pointless.

This is my jQuery:

```
    attendSelect.each(function(k, v)
    {
        attendance = $(this).val();

        if(attendance != "default")
        {   
            console.log(attendance == "default");
            students[k] = 
            {
                lesson : $(this).attr('id'),
                student_id : $(this).attr('name'),
                attendance  : attendance
            };
        }    
    });
```

This works because it prints false the correct amount of times each time I test it, in this case 3 times. However, the problem is on the server side (I think?). When I print the variable, I get NULL, NULL for the amount of times default was found in jQuery. Surely, I should be only getting an array of size 3 without NULLs.

This is what is printed in PHP:

```
$students = json_decode($_POST['students'], true);
var_dump($students);

array(12) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["lesson"]=>
    string(9) "lesson[7]"
    ["student_id"]=>
    string(12) "student[241]"
    ["attendance"]=>
    string(14) "Excused Absent"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["lesson"]=>
    string(9) "lesson[7]"
    ["student_id"]=>
    string(12) "student[270]"
    ["attendance"]=>
    string(12) "Excused Late"
  }
  [5]=>
  NULL
  [6]=>
  NULL
  [7]=>
  NULL
  [8]=>
  NULL
  [9]=>
  NULL
  [10]=>
  NULL
  [11]=>
  array(3) {
    ["lesson"]=>
    string(9) "lesson[9]"
    ["student_id"]=>
    string(12) "student[317]"
    ["attendance"]=>
    string(14) "Excused Absent"
  }
}
```

This is my AJAX:

```
students = JSON.stringify(students)

    if(attendSelect.length)//protect against submitting on past lessons
    {
        $.post('',  { students : students, cid: cid }, function(response)
        {

            console.log(response);          
        });
    }
```

I don't understand why I get NULLs when it doesn't even enter the if statement in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line here:

```
students[k] =
```

Instead, you should use `.push()`

```
students.push(
        {
            lesson : $(this).attr('id'),
            student_id : $(this).attr('name'),
            attendance  : attendance
        });
```

Your `k` value is the index of the `attendSelect` you are processing. When you are creating your students array, you are assigning those index keys instead of just creating a new array. Javascript is "filling in" the missing indexes with NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

An array in JSON can't skip indices.

You can filter out the `null` values by using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter) (don't pass anything as the second argument).